# How to edit bootstrap navbar?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make an angular app, where I am using `bootstrap@5.0.2` . There in the navbar, I have two links which I want to move it to the right. But I am unable to do it. What do I do?
[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78X7D.jpg)

HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HOMEPAGE</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <span class="navbar-text">
                <a routerLink="/homepage/registration">Registration</a>
            </span>
            <span class="navbar-text">
                <a routerLink="/homepage/login">Login</a>
            </span>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Apply css `#navbarSupportedContent{
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav{
  gap: 10px;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Apply CSS to your component*

```
#navbarSupportedContent{
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav{
  gap: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flex spacer before `ul` tag like this

```
<span class="flex-spacer"></span>
```

Add the class in css

```
.flex-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Your code will be

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HOMEPAGE</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <span class="flex-spacer"></span>
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <span class="navbar-text">
          <a routerLink="/homepage/registration">Registration</a>
        </span>
        <span class="navbar-text">
          <a routerLink="/homepage/login">Login</a>
        </span>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here's how it would look like

[image: Here's how it would look like]

Hope this helped.

Comment: Still its in the same position

Comment: Check the image,I have uploaded. You will have a better understanding of the problem

Comment: I know what you mean, i just reproduced my code on my machine, and added an image, it's working properly.